# How to change the shape of zoom in/out and home buttons in amcharts? I didn't find any solution in amcharts library. Please get me into the solution

Tags: javascript, typescript, amcharts4

I am trying to change the shape of the home button and Zoom in/out buttons by default they are in a square shape, I want to make it to circle-shaped buttons, but I didn't find any solution in Amcharts library. I am providing an image link below please check zoom in/out and home buttons. https://ibb.co/QDfXLMS  If you have any idea please suggest to me. Thank you

```
// Add zoom control
chart.zoomControl = new am4maps.ZoomControl();

chart.zoomControl.layout = "horizontal";

chart.zoomControl.marginRight = 300;
chart.zoomControl.marginLeft = 100;
chart.zoomControl.width = 30;
chart.zoomControl.plusButton.marginLeft = 10;
chart.zoomControl.plusButton.marginRight = 10;
chart.zoomControl.minusButton.marginLeft = 10;
chart.zoomControl.minusButton.marginRight = 10;
chart.zoomControl.minusButton.width = 30;

// Add button
let button = new am4core.Button();
button.icon = new am4core.Sprite();
button.icon.path =
    "M16,8 L14,8 L14,16 L10,16 L10,10 L6,10 L6,16 L2,16 L2,8 L0,8 L8,0 L16,8 Z M16,8";
button.padding(8, 5, 5, 5);
button.width = 30;
button.align = "right";
button.marginRight = 10;
button.marginLeft = 10;
button.valign = "bottom";
button.parent = chart.zoomControl;

button.events.on("hit", function() {
    chart.goHome();
});
```

[please see home button and Zoom in/out buttons in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3aeI.png)

image link: https://ibb.co/QDfXLMS

Answer (score 1):

The shape of a button is a [rounded rectangle](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/roundedrectangle/), accessible via the `background` property of the button. You can set each corner radius with `cornerRadiusBottomRight`, etc. To set the same value for the four corners, there's the method `cornerRadius`. To have a round button, set each corner radius to 50%:

```
chart.zoomControl.minusButton.background.cornerRadius(am4core.percent(50));
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. When I used "chart.zoomControl.minusButton.background.cornerRadius(am4core.percent(50));"  this line the VS code is showing "Expected 4 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
RoundedRectangle.d.ts(105, 40): An argument for 'tr' was not provided." so I slightly modified the line as "          chart.zoomControl.minusButton.background.cornerRadius(50, 50, 50, 50);
" Now it is working fine. Once again thank you.